# Web Service Request issue in C#.net WSDL

Tags: c#

We are creating a web service request for IBM Maximo web services in C#.net , the issue is  apart from for few web service requests we get succesful response for all other web services, but for some requests there is no response at all, but when we give request for the same using the SOAP UI, we get response.

Where would the problem be ? Any ideas?.

Many thanks ,
byfour

Comment: Sample use case? Code? This unfortunately looks to be a case where not much troubleshooting has been done and it is notoriously difficult to help you at this stage with nothing more than _it isn't working_.

Answer (score 1):

> Any ideas?

Start debugging. First of all, of course your application contains logging, so you can see whether any exceptions occur while sending the message.

If no exceptions occor on your end, you can [configure tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) to log all actions the WCF plumbing is executing, so you can see whether that part goes well. If it does, you can start debugging the network. If you see your message going over the wire, it's time to pick up the phone and call the other party and ask if they see anything happening after they receive your messages.